# Как связать Flask и nginx?

Tags: nginx, flask

Есть flask приложение, есть nginx. Что нужно сделать, чтобы это приложение заработало на сервере и к нему был доступ через dns, типа http://someaddress.com/application?

Comment: [Чем вам не угодила официальная документация?](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/uwsgi/)

Comment: Для доступа по хостнейму вам не обязательно использовать нгинкс. Достаточно указать в dns ip адрес сервера и запустить ваше flask приложение на порту 80. Другое дело, что nginx может помочь вам запустить и обслуживать несколько приложений.